# Finding and counting all subsequence of a string

Tags: c, string, subsequence

I'm trying to find all possible sub-sequence of a string. For example "abc" in this string we will find total 8 string 2^3=8 combinations. like a, b, c, ab, ac, bc, abc '\0'. 
But my code is only printing all character of the string. How can I do that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char string[1000];
    int count, i;
    gets(string);
    int len = strlen(string);
    for(i=0; i<len; i++) {
        printf("%c ", string[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What part of your code, in your opinion, would find these subsequences? Do you know how this code works?

Comment: What you are asking is generating all possible subsets(power set)

Comment: Do you want just to count (use math instead) or print all combinations?

Comment: Yes I wanna to find the power set of the string.

Comment: I'd rather describe the problem as "all possible subsets of characters in a string". Then, does upper/lower case matter? What is answer for "aaa"?

Comment: I have searched a lot but I didn't get my ans what am wishing to do. For example in case "aba" aa won't be counted. so the result of count of this will 7. and this is "a", "ab", "aba", "aa", "b", "ba", "a" and ""(empty string). But among the subsequences all are valid except "aa".

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, you need a totally different loop. You would loop over all positions `i` in the string; the character at each position would either be printed or not. The problem can be solved with recursion, which pehaps is easier than with an iterative approach.

Comment: I'm wishing to do this. Example: let, S = "aba" then possible subsequences are "a", "ab", "aba", "aa", "b", "ba", "a" and ""(empty string). But among the subsequences all are valid except "aa". if input for this aba then output will be: 7

Comment: I don't quite understand why "aa" would be an invalid subsequence; is that because adjacent positions are required to be different, as you write in the comment above? In your example, the subsequence "a" appears twice; should both occurences of "a" be considered different because "a" can be obtained by deletion in different ways?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is consider string as a set and use following algorithm to print all subsets

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int include[1000];
int n;
char s[1000];
int count=1;
void subsets(int i)
{   int j;
    if(i==n){
        int f=0;

        char temp[1000]="";
        int cnt=0;
        for(j=0;j<n;++j){

            if(include[j]){

                temp[cnt]=s[j];

                if(cnt>0 && temp[cnt]==temp[cnt-1]){ f=1; break;}
                ++cnt;

            }
        }
        temp[cnt]='\0';
        if(!f){ printf("%d =",count); printf("%s\n",temp);  
        ++count;}

     //printf("\n");
   }
    else{
        include[i] = 1;      // This element will be in the subset
        subsets(i + 1);
        include[i] = 0;     // This element won't be in the subset
        subsets(i + 1);
  }
}





void main(){

    scanf("%s",s);
   // printf("%s",s);
    n=strlen(s);
    subsets(0);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your ans. But Please try to implement this in C programming. Cause am a new programmer.

Comment: I'm wishing to do this. Example: let, S = "aba" then possible subsequences are "a", "ab", "aba", "aa", "b", "ba", "a" and ""(empty string). But among the subsequences all are valid except "aa". 
if input for this aba then output will be: 7

Comment: Subsequence of this string does not have same character at adjacent positions. Subsequence of string S can be obtained from deleting zero or more characters from string S. Thank you in advance.

Comment: No. I'm wishing to do this willingly. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Subsequence of this string does not have same character at adjacent positions. Subsequence of string S can be obtained from deleting zero or more characters from string S. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did the updated answer help? Or you are trying to achieve something else?